# Множества, действия над множествами

Tags: c++, c

Составить программу:
вычисления пересечения и разности двух множеств A ,B  . Вывести все перестановки элементов  множества из n элементов  и их  количество.
Мне нужно объединить две программы в одну, или может, можно решить другим методом.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n, m, sol[20], elements[20];

int element_in_set(const int a[], int n, int x) {
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
if (a[i] == x)return 1;
}
return 0;
}

void intersection_set(int a[], int n, int b[], int m, int **c, int *k) {
*k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
*k += element_in_set(b, m, a[i]);
}
*c = calloc(*k, sizeof(int));
int p = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
if (element_in_set(b, m, a[i]))
(*c)[p++] = a[i];
}

void union_set(int a[], int n, int b[], int m, int **c, int *k) {
int *c1, k1;
intersection_set(a, n, b, m, &c1, &k1);
*k = m + n - k1;
*c = calloc(*k, sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
(*c)[i] = a[i];
}
int q = n;
for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
if (!element_in_set(c1, k1, b[i]))
(*c)[q++] = b[i];
}
}

void difference_set(int a[], int n, int b[], int m, int **c, int *k) {
intersection_set(a, n, b, m, &b, &m);
*k = n - m;
*c = calloc(*k, sizeof(int));
int q = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
if (!element_in_set(b, m, a[i]))
(*c)[q++] = a[i];
}
}

int main() {
int pInt[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}, pInt1[] = {2, 3, 5, 6, 7};
int lenPInt = sizeof(pInt) / sizeof(int), lenPInt1 = sizeof(pInt1) / sizeof(int),
l, *x = NULL;
intersection_set(pInt, lenPInt, pInt1, lenPInt1, &x, &l);
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
printf("%d ", x[i]);
}
printf("\n");
union_set(pInt, lenPInt, pInt1, lenPInt1, &x, &l);
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
printf("%d ", x[i]);
}
printf("\n");
difference_set(pInt, lenPInt, pInt1, lenPInt1, &x, &l);
for (int i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
printf("%d ", x[i]);
}
printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int N, uz[16], p[16], elements[20];

unsigned long long factorial(unsigned n) {
if (!n)return 1;
else return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

void back(int nivel) {
setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
int i;

if (nivel == N + 1) {
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
printf("%d ", elements[p[i]]);
printf("\n");
return;
}

for (i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
if (!uz[i]) {
uz[i] = 1;
p[nivel] = i;
back(nivel + 1);
uz[i] = 0;
}
}

int main() {
printf("n=");
scanf("%d", &N);
printf("Умножения элементов:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
scanf("%d", elements + i + 1);
printf("Количество перестановок: %llu\n", factorial(N));
back(1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну так объедините, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно просто совместить эти проги, разделяя пространствами имён.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

namespace NS1 {

int n, m, sol[20], elements[20];
...

}

#include <stdio.h>

namespace NS2 {

int N, uz[16], p[16], elements[20];
...
}

int main(){
  NS1 :: main();
  NS2 :: main();
  }
```